# jQuery select first item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using this simple jQuery to prevent the link-redirect:

```
$("#main-nav .menu-wrapper .menu li.has-sub").find( "a" ).click(function() {
    return false;
});
```

This is my HTML:

```
<div id="main-nav">
    <div class="menu-wrapper">
        <ul class="menu">
            <!-- ONLY SELECT THIS LINK -->
            <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
            <li class="has-sub"><a href="#">Dolor Sit</a>
                <ul class="sub">
                    <!-- DO NOT SELECT THIS LINK -->
                    <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I only want to prevent the redirect of the first Link not of the second (`.sub`) link. My current script prevents the redirect of all links in my nav!

Comment: [Documentation](http://api.jquery.com)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select all first level `<a>` tags, you can use `.children` instead of `.find`

If you want to select exactly the first `<a>` tag, you can use `.find('a:first')`

By the way, I recommend you do not `return false` which could stop other possible event listeners and processes too. use `event.preventDefault();` instead

```
$("#main-nav .menu-wrapper .menu li.has-sub").find( "a:first" ).click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To select the first one is like:

```
 $("#main-nav .menu-wrapper .menu li.has-sub").find( "a" ).eq(0).click(function() {
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Why the downvote?

According to jQuery's source code, .first() is just a convenience wrapper for .eq(0):

first: function() { return this.eq( 0 ); },

src: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/bf48c21d225c31f0f9b5441d95f73615ca3dcfdb/src/core.js#L91

Answer (score 0):

Choose first one like this

```
 $("#main-nav .menu-wrapper .menu li.has-sub").find( "a" ).first().click(fucntion(){
     ...
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$("#main-nav .menu-wrapper .menu li.has-sub a:first").click(function() {

    return false;

});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you have only one `<a>` in the first level of children. So, you could use `children()` instead of `find()`, like this:

```
$("#main-nav .menu-wrapper .menu li.has-sub").children("a").click(function() {
    return false;
});
```

> The .children() method differs from .find() in that .children() only travels a single level down the DOM tree while .find() can traverse down multiple levels to select descendant elements (grandchildren, etc.) as well.